# Updating a Table Through VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table with property data, like adress, postal code etc, that i have to find a way to add or delete entries in the table that contains all of the data. To make the program idiot-proof, the code hide the unnecessary buttons to the task, except the button to conclude the task, either add or delete entries.The database is in another sheet, for idiot-proof reasons. i searched for solutions, but nothing exactly helped, so i have some questions, and if someone can explain i'll be very grateful.

1 - How do i create a new line within the Table2, without creating a new line in the sheet?

2 - I have three tables in the same sheet, for quickening the process of the work, but for more reusability of the code, and more idiot-proofness, maybe better to have only one table for sheet?

3 - When i delete a cell/row of data in the Table2, will it move the others cells/rows? Or i will be with a blank space in the Table2? What is the better approach to this problem? Because i expect to have some changes in a while in the Table2 and dont want to always interacting directly with the table.

I updated the Workbook in my GitHub: https://github.com/carlosefrbarros/Email-Sender-System
Any help will be valuable = )

EDIT: Here is the piece of code

```
Sub EndAddProperty()

    'Hide Ok Button and unhide others buttons
    Sheets("Property File").Shapes("Sheet4Button7").Visible = True
    Sheets("Property File").Shapes("Sheet4Button8").Visible = True
    Sheets("Property File").Shapes("Sheet4Button9").Visible = True
    Sheets("Property File").Shapes("Sheet4Button10").Visible = True
    Sheets("Property File").Shapes("Sheet4Button12").Visible = False

    'Lock Cells
    Sheets("Property File").Range("I3:N3").Locked = True
    Sheets("Property File").Range("I6:N6").Locked = True
    Sheets("Property File").Range("I9:N9").Locked = True
    Sheets("Property File").Range("I12:N12").Locked = True
    Sheets("Property File").Range("I15:N18").Locked = True

    'Check if the Code of property exist and if does, exit sub
    For Each Cell In Sheets("Database").Range("D1:D100")
        If Sheets("Property File").Range("F3").Value = Cell.Value Then
            MsgBox "This code already exist."
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
    
    'If the Code of Property doesnt exist, update the data in the Table2



End Sub
```

And putting in simpler terms, how do i add or delete info from a table in a sheet, using VBA.

Comment: You're not a new poster here, so you know how it works best: ask a specific question, preferably including the relevant code and a description of the problem you're having.

Comment: @TimWilliams Edited the question, but i really dont have much clue how to initially approach this question, because of this, that i posted like this. If you have some tutorial or link to share that take care of tables in VBA, i'll be very grateful, the ones that i've found, doesnt answered my needs  = )

Comment: For example: adding a new row - https://www.bluepecantraining.com/portfolio/excel-vba-how-to-add-rows-and-columns-to-excel-table-with-vba-macro/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add sheet rows you must insert cells. It's possible to insert precisely those cells which are below a table and expand the table to include them. It's called adding a table row. There are menu options for this which you can click and record.

What Excel will not tell you, however, is that inserting cells (partial sheet rows) causes trouble with the formatting of the remaining parts of the modified sheet row. Simply put, if a sheet row has a height of 25pt you can't insert cells (a partial sheet row) with a different height.

The problem gets even worse if your tables are below one another. Adding a sheet row higher up just pushes the lower tables down by a row. But adding a table row pushes only contents down while leaving formatting in place, probably messing up the tables below. Same for deletions.

Therefore my advice is to either stick with a single table per sheet or insist on sheet rows being added.

Comment: Thank you! I was already thinking in one table per sheet, but your answer clarify that is the best approach to the problem. If i gonna insert sheet rows, you know how to adjust the range of the table to include the newer row? And if i delete the sheet row, the range of the table will adjust automatically? Or its gonna keep with a blank row? I'll look in adding table row, to see if i found a good option. Thanks! ^^